# Mysterious Core Data Faulting Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am experiencing a mysterious Core Data crash via crash reports in my app, that I am having difficulty coming up with a theory for. No reproduction steps, no obvious causes, but it occurs many thousand times. The crash report is pretty vague but it seems to happen when an `NSManagedObject` is assigned via property to another? Any theories would be appreciated.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x1dc92160 <x-coredata://6903F7F9-C600-4A29-A538-B3337F1D0BED/Profile/p47854>''

Last Exception Backtrace:
1    CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 163
2    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_throw + 30
3    CoreData    _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1477
4    CoreData    _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 203
5    CoreData    _PF_ManagedObject_WillChangeValueForKeywithSetMutation + 71
6    CoreData    -[NSManagedObject willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:] + 84
7    CoreData    -[NSManagedObject _includeObject:intoPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] + 690
8    CoreData    -[NSManagedObject _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 444
9    CoreData    -[NSManagedObject _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1290
10   CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 322
11   Foundation  NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 273
12   Foundation  NSKeyValueDidChange + 335
13   Foundation  -[NSObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 94
14   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 126
15   CoreData    -[NSManagedObject _updateFromRefreshSnapshot:includingTransients:] + 614
16   CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext _copyChildObject:toParentObject:fromChildContext:] + 96
17   CoreData    -[NSManagedObjectContext _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 554
18   CoreData    __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke_0 + 565
19   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 81
20   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout + 23
21   libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$up + 227
22   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1291
23   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
24   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
25   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74
26   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
27   My App  main (main.m:18)
28   libdyld.dylib   start + 0
```

Comment: Is there any place in your code where you share NSManagedObjects between different threads? For example, you fetch objects on the main thread and then put them in dispatch_async(background_queue...) for processing. Or maybe you access NSManagedObjectContext which was created on the main thread from other threads?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, and there's been a lot of work done to avoid that kind of thing.

Comment: @MishaKarpenko is probably on the right path. This smells like a threading issue. Fault errors like this normally happen when the thread boundary has been violated.

Answer (score 2):

“CoreData could not fulfill a fault” usually happens when you delete some object from the persistent store using one context, but in another context this object still exists, it is a fault, and you try to access some property of it.

Don’t forget that an object can be deleted as a result of cascade deletion rule for a relationship.

Here’s the possible timeline:

1. The object is fetched in context A. By default it is a fault.
2. The object representing the same data in the store is fetched in context B.
3. The object is deleted in context B.
4. Context B is saved resulting in data deleted from the store.
5. Some property of the object from context A is accessed.
6. The fault is being fired. Core Data tries to fulfill the fault, but there’s no data in the persistent store anymore.

Comment: I understand faulting and so forth, I'm just at a loss to actually track down where in the app the problem lies, exactly. Normally, if I try and access a fault that cannot be unfaulted, the stack trace would point to the location, providing some clue for a fix. In this case it seems to happen in some sort of background process I have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

If an object that was already fetched has been deleted on another thread or in a different ManagedObjectContext, it is possible that you receive an exception when you try to access a property of the deleted object.

This is due to faulting which is described here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html